# JSON me imprime dos veces el resultado de una consulta

Tags: php, json

Tengo una consulta en PHP

**Modelo**

```
public static function mostrarSlideIDModel($datosModel, $tabla){

    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id_slide, marca_slide, desc_slide, liga_slide, imagen_slide FROM $tabla WHERE id_slide = :id");

    $stmt -> bindParam(":id", $datosModel["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);

    $stmt -> execute();

    return $stmt -> fetch();

    $stmt -> close();
}
```

**Controlador:**

```
public static function mostrarSlideIDController(){

        $datosController = array("id"   =>  $_POST['idSlide']);

        $respuesta = SlideModel::mostrarSlideIDModel($datosController, "slides");

        echo json_encode($respuesta);
    }
```

y al visualizar en el navegador, en el response de AJAX, me imprime dos veces la informacion, una con indice y la otra con el nombre de la columna.

Ejemplo:

```
      "0":48,
      "1":"Nets",
      "2":"Optiviework",
      "3":"http://www.lorem.com/marcas/file.php",
      "4":"banner-131.jpg",
      "id_slide":48,
      "marca_slide":"Nets",
      "desc_slide":"Optiviework",
      "liga_slide":"http://www.lorem.com/marcas/file.php",
      "imagen_slide":"banner-131.jpg"
```

No se que tan correcto puede ser esto, son de las primeras veces que manejo datos en JSON. Ojala alguien me pueda orientar, Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que la funcion `fetch` usa un parametro cuyo valor por default retorna un array asociativo y un array con indices.  Si quieres ver solo una de estas dos opciones, necesitas especificar el parametro asi:

```
return $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```